# не работает команда echo в html странице. После преобразования html в php главная страница не работает. В чем проблема?

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Личный сайт студентки GeekBrains</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
    <a href="puzzle.html">Загадки</a>
    <a href="guess.html">Угадайка</a>
</div>
    <h1>Личный сайт студентки Geekbrains.</h1>

    <div class="center">
    <img src="C:\Users\татевик\Desktop\img/photo.jpg">
    <div class="box_text">

    <p><b>Добрый день.</b> <i>Меня зовут Тата</i>. Я совсем недавно начала программировать, однако уже написала свой первый сайт.</p>

    <p>В этом мне помог IT-портал <a href="https://geekbrains.ru/"> GeekBrains</a></p>

    <p>На этом сайте вы сможете сыграть в неcколько игр, которые я написала.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Copyright &copy; <?php echo date("Y");?> TataKhachatrian
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а Вы после преобразования html в php страницу как просматриваете?

Comment: Я прохожу курс, там объясняли так: добавляем код php в html страницу и в название добавляем php. Сделала как сказали, но год на сайте не отображается и главная страница не работает. Когда убираю php из название, главная работает, года все также не видно

Comment: пишет not found

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос: Вы как запускаете php-файл? Просто с рабочего стола/из папки как обычный html-файл?

Comment: Запускаю из папки на рабочем столе.

Comment: Дело в том, что php-файл так запустить нельзя. Чтобы работал php, нужен сервер. Для локальной разработки подойдёт OpenServer, например

Comment: То есть, по факту я выполнила верно, просто без сервера оно не отображается?

Comment: да, именно так и есть

Comment: Все ясно, огромное спасибо!

Comment: На курсе что не сообщали про вебсервера? И как вообще запускать php-скрипты?

Comment: Видимо сообщали, просто в одно ухо влетело, а в другое вылетело, да, @Татевик? ;)

Comment: Про сервера сообщали, но про то, что нельзя просматривать в Google нет) Там введение в программирование, php не изучается, пару небольших заданий, чтобы добавить на сайт год и пароль) @DanielProtopopov